# Why is the size of class E 24 bytes in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
 int a;
};
class B: virtual public A{};
class C: virtual public A{};

 
class X{
public:
 int c;
};

class D: public B, public C{
};

class E: public D, virtual public X{
};
class F:virtual public X{
};
int main() {
 cout <<sizeof (E) << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

b inherits a,c inherits a,d inherits b and c，e inherits d and x
Why is the size of class E 24 bytes in c++
GCC+MinGW-w64 compiler for Windows

Comment: what do you expect it to be?

Comment: The size of the class is what it is because of the ABI that the compiler conforms to.

Comment: For the multiple virtual inheritance you need two pointers (implementations may differ) with 8 bytes each, add two int variables with 4 bytes each and you get 24 bytes.

Comment: The class size also include intra- and juxta- padding/alignment bytes (if any), the behind-the-scenes virtual function table pointer, and behind-the-scenes virtual inheritance traversal machinery.  In general, none of those things are accessible to the programmer through what is provided by C++.

Comment: If you are interested in the internals, read the ABIs or Lippman's book *Inside the C++ Object Model*